# How do I prevent the Browser and Dolphin HD from deleting old history entries?

Tags: settings, browser, dolphin-browser

So I've noticed that for both the default browser and for the Dolphin HD browser, all the history entries get deleted when you go beyond a certain number of pages visited. Does anyone know how I can prevent this from happening? I often do like to look at what I visited in the far past.

Comment: There is no more Dolphin HD. It is just Dolphin now (and Dolphin Jetpack). How many history entries do you have? I still have my history from last month.

Comment: In the current application, Dolphin Browser,  under settings > Privacy > under  "Clear data" and under "Clear data when exiting"

Answer (score 0):

### **Dolphin Settings**

Well, for starters, I'm looking at my own Dolphin Browser Settings page right now and under **Data** settings, you have the option to manually clear certain data types like *history* and *cookies* and also have the option to manually back the data up to your local or external (SD) storage disk.

### **Data Backup**

In addition, under **Sync** settings, you can actually backup an unlimited amount of your history, bookmarks, cookies, etc. to your Dolphin Connect Account (which you can connect to Google or other social services). So that may be an option you may want to look into, is data backup so you'll actually have access to unlimited amount of the data you use from any device you use Dolphin on, despite Dolphin's local limit.

[image: As you can see, you can sync all types of data and settings! :)]

### **Drawing The Line**

As far as I'm concerned (and someone, correct me if I'm wrong), at this stage I don't know that there is an option for you. The new Dolphin Browser doesn't have any limit so I'm not sure how much assistance any one of us will be knowing that Dolphin HD is an outdated version of Dolphin which is no longer supported.

The new Dolphin Browser can be found [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser&hl=en).

Good luck and let me know if I can help any further! I'll continue looking in the meantime, but it is doubtful that I'd find much.